# Unable to connect to Heroku postgre SQL database locally

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to connect to Heroku postgre SQL database locally like this,

```
from flask import Flask
import sys
import psycopg2
import urlparse

urlparse.uses_netloc.append("postgres")
url = urlparse.urlparse("postgres://url")

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    database=url.path[1:],
    user=url.username,
    password=url.password,
    host=url.hostname,
    port=url.port
)
```

But after a lengthy pause I get the following error,

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "URL" (IP) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

How can I fix this error and connect to the database locally?

Answer (score 0):

Kinda tough for me to narrow down, but I was able to set something similar with these steps:

If you have a 'server.py' make sure to have this at the top of the file:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
db = pg.DB(
  dbname=os.environ.get('DBNAME'),
  host=os.environ.get('DBHOST'),
  port=int(os.environ.get('DBPORT')),
  user=os.environ.get('DBUSER'),
  passwd=os.environ.get('DBPASSWORD')
)
```

Dump the following in a Procfile (spell Procfile exactly like that)

```
web: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 4 server:app
```

Lastly, you need a requirements.txt that lists all Python modules you have installed. You can do this with the command: pip freeze > requirements.txt

Hope that helps.